# json SerDe hive 0.13.1

Tags: json, hive, cloudera

**I'm trying to create a hive table in wich I will load json data.**

Here is what I did:

**1 -** I downloaded the project https://github.com/sheetaldolas/Hive-JSON-Serde/tree/master and changed the cdh5 version to cdh5.2.0 (the cloudera version that I use)

**2-** I added the jar from the serde project

```
.../Hive-JSON-Serde-develop/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**3-** I tried to create a table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE events (..XYZ..)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true") STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

here XYZ is correct because the table is created if I remove the "ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true")" part

**And I'm getting a serde error:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.AbstractPrimitiveJavaObjectInspector.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils$PrimitiveTypeEntry;)V
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:277)
    at com.seb.hive.Standard.importStandardEvents(Standard.java:90)
    at com.seb.hive.Standard.main(Standard.java:37)
```

**I checked the /tmp/{user}/hive.log but there is nothing:**

```
/tmp/cloudera/hive.log 
2014-12-10 02:26:04,535 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(360)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
```

**My hive version is 0.13.1 and I saw that there were problems with this version of hive**
http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/json-serde-not-working-in-hive-0-13-0/
but I downloaded the last version from the repository..so it should be fixed...

**What should I also check? Is my approach correcte?**

Thank you!

Comment: I managed to solve it by getting the version 2 of the serde library from https://code.google.com/p/hive-json-serde/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by getting the version 2 of the serde library from code.google.com/p/hive-json-serde/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

I have explained how to handle json data in Hive in this video. I think you didn't added json data jars in your hive/lib folder. you can download those jar files from http://files.cloudera.com/samples/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and https://code.google.com/p/hive-json-serde/downloads/list

Please note json data and rejex serde too overhead problems. so take care.. 
Useful link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fqxeGUBLiQ

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.